# Obtain the sum of the total disk usage

Tags: powershell

I want to get the sum of the result in "UsedSpace_GB" of all the units, I use the following script to get the information

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='3'" | ForEach {
 New-Object PSObject -Property @{
  Name = $_.Name
  Label = $_.Label
  FreeSpace_GB = ([Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace /1GB,2))
  TotalSize_GB = ([Math]::Round($_.Capacity /1GB,2))
  UsedSpace_GB = ([Math]::Round($_.Capacity /1GB,2)) - ([Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace /1GB,2))
  }
     }
```

I get the following result

[image]

or if there is some other way to get the total usage of all the disk

Comment: If you want to know the sizes of the disk, then get the disk information, instead of the volume information. As you've seen there can be many volumes/partitions on each disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified one-liner that will sum them up:

```
$total=0;Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='3'" | ForEach-Object {$total += [Math]::Round((($_.Capacity - $_.FreeSpace) / 1GB),2)};Write-Output "TotalUsedSpace_GB : $total"
```